# Applying stylization on batches causes problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I am currently using the [stylization module of TF-Hub](https://tfhub.dev/google/magenta/arbitrary-image-stylization-v1-256/2) for a set of experiments where I am applying stylization at random on a set of images.

After applying stylization, the images are coming out as the following:

[image]

I am using the Cats-vs.-Dogs dataset and I am loading it using the following code listing:

```py
train_ds, validation_ds = tfds.load(
    'cats_vs_dogs',
    split=['train[:85%]', 'train[85%:]'],
    as_supervised=True
)
```

After this, I am creating a utility function to apply the stylization module to a given image and I am mapping that utility like so -

```py
train_ds = (
    train_ds
    .map(preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    .shuffle(1024)
    .map(apply_random_stylization, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    .prefetch(AUTO)
)
```

`apply_random_stylization` is defined as -

```py
def apply_random_stylization(image, label):
    image = random_apply(stylize_image, image, p=0.8)
    return (image, label)

def random_apply(func, x, p):
        return tf.cond(
          tf.less(tf.random.uniform([], minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32),
                  tf.cast(p, tf.float32)),
          lambda: func(x),
          lambda: x)

def stylize_image(image):
    stylized_image = HUB_MODULE(tf.expand_dims(image, 0), tf.constant(STYLE_IMG))[0]
    stylized_image = tf.squeeze(stylized_image)
    return tf.clip_by_value(stylized_image, 0., 1.)
```

Here's the [Colab Gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/sayakpaul/2c5dbcce0ec659c9b9e5be0149304c35/scratchpad.ipynb) that reproduces this issue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [model page](https://tfhub.dev/google/magenta/arbitrary-image-stylization-v1-256/2) says that the content image and the style image need to be normalized to [0, 1]. Dividing the passed images in `parse_single` and `preprocess_image` by 255 gives the following results:
[image]